# Logic Gate Cookbook

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, computer-architecture, logic-gates, reference-materials

Is there a concise book that brings together all of the different Logic devices that can be implemented with basic logic gates?

I have several digital/computer architecture books that have the different devices I need, but I was wondering if somebody had compiled them into a single body of work.

I'm working on FPGA design and I would find it very helpful to have a quick reference to various Logic devices that  I can implement in my code and on my fpga. Please feel free to share your resources!

Comment: ALL devices? I't like infinite number...

Comment: If such a thing existed, why would we ever need logic designers?

Comment: I'm assuming you were the one who thumbed down my question. You didn't provide any kind of logical (no pun intended) reason as to why there isn't one that exists. I'm not asking about every single obscure possibility. I was asking if a document existed that showcased the most commonly used devices. There's tons of cookbooks that exist on opamps, BJTs, etc...

Comment: I will admit that I was the one who downvoted the question, and it has several reasons. First, it is violating several rules of SE (book/product recommendation, too broad, primarily opinion based). Second, as I have said before, as in any engineering field, one single book can cover the basics and the most common constructs. I.e. give you the building blocks, which you are, as an engineer can arrange for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for any such book. The reason is that "all of the different Logic devices that can be implemented with basic logic gates" is just all the possible truth tables that can be constructed with any particular number of inputs. So a book of all the possible gates would be the equivalent of a list of all the numbers between 0 and 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

In FPGAs, all gates are generally implemented as look-up tables (LUTs) anyway, so there's no performance difference between a "basic" gate like NAND and a complex gate like XOR. Just design the logic table that solves the problem you want and let the synthesis tool sort it out. If you need more inputs than the LUTs in your FPGA, then you might need to start thinking about how to partition the logic to minimize propagation delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I didn't ask the question properly which may have led to some confusion. There exists books on things like how to design a common-emitter, emitter-follower, using a single supply op-amp, etc. There also exists cookbooks on 555 timers. I am not asking if a book exists on how to make a circuit for every single possible truth table, just a simple reference for common configurations like comparators, multiplexers, full-adders, etc. Am I crazy for thinking this would be a nice thing to have handy?

Comment: @wunjo, For FPGA design, look for the Design Guides from your FPGA vendor. They won't show you how to design those things from gates, but they will show the preferred VHDL or Verilog code to produce them, which is much more useful.